# How to find lat/long from create type

Tags: sql, postgresql, sqldatatypes

I have the following in my database and I need the values of long and lat. How do I call for them?

```
CREATE TYPE GeoCoord AS
(Latitude DECIMAL,
 Longitude DECIMAL);
```

In table Mountain:

```
Coordinates GeoCoord CONSTRAINT MountainCoord
```

Comment: It's my professor that's created the database...
When I write as you suggest I only get error message: geocoord is a composite type

Comment: `CREATE TYPE` as a table column datatype?  Most off the time `CREATE TYPE` will be used for return types for functions.. `CREATE DOMAIN` is more meant for table column datatypes.

Comment: @RaymondNijland that's not true. And a domain can't be used to define a composite type.

Comment: Well maybe i explained it wrong @a_horse_with_no_name the added feature of `CREATE DOMAIN` vs `CREATE TYPE` is that `CREATE DOMAIN` has a `CHECK` feature which makes `CREATE DOMAIN` more usefull for table datatypes that is what i meant..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[As documented in the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/static/sql-expressions.html#FIELD-SELECTION) you need to put parentheses around the column to access each field in the type.

> An important special case is extracting a field from a table column that is of a composite type ... The parentheses are required here to show that compositecol is a column name not a table name

So you need to write:

```
select (coordinates).latitude, 
       (coordinates).longitude
from mountain;
```

Online example: http://rextester.com/AOAC81213